# What is the little box with an A in pyqtgraph/PyQt Viewbox with a little box and an A inside and how to get rid of it?

Tags: python, plot, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am using pyqtgraph and trying to use a histogramLUTable inside of a viewbox to try and plot some data and I have this black box with a little A that is obstructing the graph origin/axis in the lower left hand corner and I can't seem to find what it is named and/or how to get rid of it. I attached a picture with a little red box around what I am talking about.

The image in question with little red box circling what I am referring to:
There is also a little black box on the lower right hadn side obfuscating the x axis but doesn't go into the level adjustment on the right hand side.

image showing issue with first code written :
[image: image showing issue with first code written]

For reference, my code so far:

```
import PyQt5
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyqtgraph as pg

up = np.linspace(0,1,100)
down = np.flip(up)
nparray = np.hstack([up, down])
data = np.vstack([[nparray], [nparray],[nparray]])
data = np.transpose(data)

app = QtGui.QApplication([]) 
win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True, title="pyqtGraph attempt", size=[800,600]) 

view = pg.PlotItem() 
win.addItem(view)
img = pg.ImageItem(data, border='w') 
histogram = pg.HistogramLUTItem()  
histogram.setImageItem(img) 
win.addItem(histogram) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.mkQApp().exec_()
```

EDIT (again):
I took a different approach to try and mitigate the little black box by using a plotItem and Viewbox rather than the HistogramLUTable but when I go this route I get the same issue. Originally I said this gives me another black box in the lower right hand corner but if you look at my original screen shot the black box is there originally as well.

```
import PyQt5
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyqtgraph as pg

up = np.linspace(0,1,100)
down = np.flip(up)
nparray = np.hstack([up, down])
data = np.vstack([[nparray], [nparray],[nparray]])

app = QtGui.QApplication([]) 
win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show=True, title="pyqtGraph attempt", size=[800,600])  
view = pg.PlotItem() 
view.hideButtons()
win.addItem(view) 
img = pg.ImageItem() 
view.addItem(img)
img.setImage(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.mkQApp().exec_()
```

image showing issue with second code written:
[image: image showing issue with second code written]

Comment: What version of pyqtgraph do you use and how did you install it? I do not reproduce the problem: https://i.imgur.com/ptawXal.png

Comment: version 0.12.0  and I installed using 'pip install pyqtgraph' as recommended on the main pyqtgraph webpage... also using anaconda for virtual environments if that is of any use

Comment: I do not reproduce the problem, but I recommend you try with the most updated version(`python -m pip install pyqtgraph==0.12.1`) or a previous version (`python -m pip install pyqtgraph==0.11.1`) since it may be a bug

Comment: Yea I just upgraded to 0.12.1 and no luck ... I'm relatively new to pyqtgraph but is it possible that there are some system wide variables/setting for pyqtgraph that are causing this problem?  If so do you know where  I can find these settings/variables?

Comment: Maybe the bug depends on the OS, what OS are you using? Have you tried on another OS?

Comment: Windows 10, and have not tried different OS but may spin up an Arch linux VM and try, just may take me a little bit as I don't have any VMs set up for python development but I guess it shouldn't too long.  What OS did you try on?

Comment: I use arch linux

Answer (score 3):

This element is a button that allows the plot to auto-scale, therefore it appears when you zoom. One possible solution is to hide it using [`hideButtons()`](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/plotitem.html#pyqtgraph.PlotItem.hideButtons) method:

```
view = pg.PlotItem()
view.hideButtons()
win.addItem(view)
```

Comment: Hey, so I tried this and it seems to hide the A but doesnt seem to hide the black box that was behind it... Upon further investigation I also noticed that I have a little black box in the lower right hand corner as well that obfuscates the x axis numbers/legend/Im forgetting the name but its the thing that displays the numbers for the x axis...

Comment: @user1884295 I don't get that black box. Are you using the latest versions of pyqtgraph? It seems to me that it is a bug.

Comment: @user1884295 Please do not put code in the comments as they are ugly, better edit your post and explain how that code is different. Also read [ask] and review the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of playing with the code the issue appeared to be using:
`app = QtGui.QApplication([])`
in conjunction with:
`pg.mkQApp().exec_()`
It causes issues, I assume from interfering with each other, because your trying to call two application execution methods but this is just an assumption.

Preferred solution if using pyqtgraph is to stick with removing

```
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
```

altogether and only including

```
if __name__ == '__main__': pg.mkQapp().exec_()
```

But an alternate also includes using

```
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
```

with

```
if __name__ == '__main__': app.exec_()
```

But it depends on how you are using pyqtgraph, if you are using it for it's graphing methods then you will probably need to use `app.addItem(plotItem)` and therefore you need to call `app.exec_()` however if you allow pyqtgraph to take care of generating the GUI you can let it take care of executing the application via `pg.mkQapp().exec_()`